# TDD data from func not being returned in XCTest case Swift

Tags: swift, tdd, xctest

This is what I have in my QuickAddViewController.swift file

```
let exercisesData = ExerciseDatabase()

var workoutTypesDictionary = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Array<String>>>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    workoutTypesDictionary = self.exercisesData.exercisesByWorkoutType

}

func getWorkoutTypes() -> [String] {
    var workoutTypesArray : [String] = []
    for workoutType in workoutTypesDictionary.keys {
        workoutTypesArray.append(workoutType)
    }

    return workoutTypesArray
}
```

This is my QuickAddViewTest.swift file

```
class QuickAddViewTests: XCTestCase {

var quickAddViewController : QuickAddViewController!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    quickAddViewController = QuickAddViewController()
}

override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
}

func testGetWorkoutTypes() {

    let workoutTypesArray = quickAddViewController.getWorkoutTypes()

    let expectedArray = ["Weight Training", "Sports & Recreation", "Body Weight", "Cardio"]

    print("Workout Array: \(workoutTypesArray)")

    print("Expected Array: \(expectedArray)")

    XCTAssertEqual(workoutTypesArray, expectedArray)

}
```

When I run the app and print getWorkoutTypes(), the function return the correct values. However, when I try to return the same values in testGetWorkoutTypes(), nothing gets returned and my test fails.

Comment: Is viewDidLoad() even being called? Print something there then report back about it. Is QuickAddViewController defined in a Storyboard or in a xib/nib file?

Comment: QuickAddViewController is in the Storyboard and does print out the expected result when the function getWorkoutTypes() is called in viewDidLoad(). What I can't figure out is why getWorkoutTypes() returns nothing in the test case.

Comment: How do you manually instantiate a storyboard instance? Look it up. Only going through the normal instantiation viewDidLoad will probably be called.

Comment: Or you could lazily instantiate wokoutTypesDictionary so you avoid viewDidLoad. Dunno whether calling viewDidLoad yourself crashes in super.viewDidLoad or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
quickAddViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

This causes wires up storyboard connections (which makes other testing possible) and triggers a call back to `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked after calling loadViewIfNeeded() after instantiating quickAddViewController in my setUp().